# H2O flow - save to html/pdf as a report

Tags: jupyter, h2o

Is there a way to save h2o flow cells after training, in form of a HTML or PDF report? I would like to achieve similar result to Jupyter Notebook, full of figures, tables etc. - a static overview of what happened. "Save flow" option saves static text, but removes figures and pictures.

So far I've tried to use primitive approach - just "save as HTML full page" in Chrome/Firefox/Safari/Edge, but the result is either empty page, or just a first cell with missing graphic elements.

I was using static Jupyter notebooks as a form of report for my Clients, and I'd like to use H2O Flow in a similar way.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to do a "print to pdf" from the browser.  On a Mac, you'd go to File -> Print -> click on the PDF button -> Save to PDF.

[image]

Here's an [example](https://s3.amazonaws.com/erin-data/stackoverflow/H2OFlow_iris_AutoML.pdf) of the PDF output for a simple AutoML run on the iris dataset.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the response! Yep, we've figured it out yesterday, although formatting is far from being perfect. In H2O flow you can add descriptive cells with headers etc., so I was pretty sure, that it is report-generating friendly :) Again - thanks